# Derivation of Boundary Conditions

Tags: electromagnetism, boundary-conditions

[image: Picture]

[image: Equations 1 and 2]

Source: http://my.ece.ucsb.edu/York/Bobsclass/201C/Handouts/Chap1.pdf (page 6).

I am trying to make sense of the derivation on the right side of these two integrals.

The first one which says that the surface integral of $D$ on the boundary (that is when $\Delta$h and $\Delta$A become infinitesimal) is the difference in the $D$ between surface 1 and 2 multiplied by the area $\Delta A$. But how? At the boundary, I do not understand what is going on.

The second integral value is just the charge enclosed on the surface, but $\rho_{se}$ is the electric charge density on which surface (that is surface in region 1 or region 2)?

I followed a couple of text books, my teachers' lecture slides, plus other resources but I am unable to understand this. Also, if someone could please teach me how to fish rather than give me the fish (find answers to my questions on my own rather than give the direct answer..like where did my thinking go wrong) that would be great.

Comment: The region or area $\Delta A$ is not going to zero. Only $\Delta h$ is.

Comment: That would make most sense because we are just trying to be at the boundary(...although this on page 6 says http://my.ece.ucsb.edu/York/Bobsclass/201C/Handouts/Chap1.pdf $\Delta A$ is also going to 0). 

I could not relate the information to possible answer to my question if that was your intent

Comment: My comment was for the mathematical step shown in the supplied image only.